# add-from-autocomplete-only = "false" with auto-complete in ngInputTag Control not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, tags, ng-tags-input

After spending a lot of time in investigating to resolve the issue to allow any tag along with autocomplete feature in **ngInputTag**. I end up with no results.
The issue is when I type the text which is in autocomplete list the tags get added successfully but when point comes to add the tags which is not in the tag list it accepting the first tag but when I enter second tag which is not in autocomplete list it makes the text color Red and not accepting the tag input.

To resolve the issue I have used **on-tag-added** but it did not worked. Same issue has been reported on Git-Hub [Issue Link](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/689)

Below is my code:
**HTML**

```
 <tags-input ng-model="model" display-property="Name" key-property="Key"
             placeholder="Enter Tags" add-from-autocomplete-only="false"
             allow-leftover-text="true">
          <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"
                         highlight-matched-text="true"
                         select-first-match="true">
          </auto-complete>
 </tags-input>
```

**Controller JS Code:**

```
$scope.model = [];
 $scope.loadTags = function (query) { 
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get(ApiUrls.GetTagsByQuery + (query != null ? ("?query=" + query) : ""))
                .then(function (result) { 
                    if (result.data == null) {
                        result = [];
                    }
                    deferred.resolve(result.data);
                },
                function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Any Help will be Highly Appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem !!! But if you remove key-property then it will works.

key-property is only for duplicate issue

Comment: After my question, the new version of this library is released in which this issue is resolved by just writing text without key.